# Disable binary logging in MySQL/8 for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-8.0

I want to disable binary logging in order to diagnose some uninteresting issue. I've never used replication anyway—it's enabled only because it's the default in MySQL/8. Google shows like 20 different ways to do it and none seem to work in my set up.

The [official manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) says:

> To disable binary logging, you can specify the `--skip-log-bin` or
> `--disable-log-bin` option at startup.

It runs as Windows service, installed with the official MySQL Installer application, so I used regedit (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL80\ImagePath), but either flags, in any location, either standalone or with `=1`, prevent the service from starting yet log file doesn't include any error message.

I've also read you can have this in defaults file:

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
```

Server starts, bug binary logging remains enabled.

Setting an `MYSQLD_OPTS` environment variable with `--skip-log-bin=1` is ignored (perhaps it's exclusive to some Linux distro).

How do you disable binary logging in MySQL/8 on Windows?

---

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL80\ImagePath**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```

**C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini**:

```
[client]
port=3306

[mysql]
no-beep

[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="FOO.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="FOO-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
# One of my failed attempts:
skip-log-bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the issue is related to the order of operations.

> If the --skip-log-bin or --disable-log-bin option is specified at
> startup, binary logging is disabled, with the log_bin system variable
> set to OFF. ***If either of these options is specified and --log-bin is
> also specified, the option specified later takes precedence.*** [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin)

### Configuration Options

By default MySQL sets a configuration value of `log-bin="FOO.bin"`, you would need to ensure that `skip-log-bin` is declared **BELOW or AFTER** the `log-bin` configuration option.

*C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini*

```
[mysqld]

#...

log-bin="FOO.bin"
skip-log-bin
```

After saving the configuration file, restart the MySQL service.

```sql
SELECT @@GLOBAL.log_bin, @@GLOBAL.version, @@GLOBAL.version_comment, @@GLOBAL.version_compile_os;
```

Result

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.log_bin | @@GLOBAL.version | @@GLOBAL.version_comment     | @@GLOBAL.version_compile_os |
+------------------+------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                0 | 8.0.21           | MySQL Community Server - GPL | Win64                       |
+------------------+------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Testing with `skip-log-bin` being declared prior to or above `log-bin`, even when using `log-bin=0` or `log-bin=OFF` resulted in the `log-bin` declaration taking precedence - converting the specified `log-bin` value to a string.

Removing the `log-bin` declaration and declaring `skip-log-bin` anywhere, resulted in `log_bin` as `OFF`

---

### Environment Variables

The environment variable `MYSQLD_OPTS` is specific to `systemd` (Linux) environments. [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-systemd.html#systemd-mysql-configuration) [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html#idm45960492368272)

There does not appear to be an equivalent environment variable for Windows. [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html) Which I believe do not apply when running MySQL as a Windows service.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me after I've declared `disable_log_bin` and  commented the `log-bin` in my.cnf.

Comment: It seems `disable_log_bin` is a synonym of `skip_log_bin`. You can use either to disable binary logs ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html)).